# uclinux compilation error

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile uclinux using a toolchain provided by the hardarware manufacturer.

When I run the `make` command, I get an error that I cannot understand:

```
yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$ make
make -C tools/ucfront
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yannick/uclinux-dist/tools/ucfront'
make[1]: `ucfront' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yannick/uclinux-dist/tools/ucfront'
ln -sf /home/yannick/uclinux-dist/tools/ucfront/ucfront tools/ucfront-gcc
ln -sf /home/yannick/uclinux-dist/tools/ucfront/ucfront tools/ucfront-g++
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-uclinux-elf- -C linux-2.6.x  || exit 1
make[1]: arm-uclinux-elf-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yannick/uclinux-dist/linux-2.6.x'
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
make[2]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
/bin/sh: 1: arm-uclinux-elf-gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s] Error 127
make[1]: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yannick/uclinux-dist/linux-2.6.x'
make: *** [linux] Error 1

yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$ locate arm-uclinux-elf-gcc
...
/usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/bin/arm-uclinux-elf-gcc
...

yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$ ls -l /usr/local/bin
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 May 20 22:53 arm-uclinux-elf-gcc -> /usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/bin/arm-uclinux-elf-gcc
...

yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$ ls -l /usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/bin/
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   81832 May 20 19:27 arm-uclinux-elf-gcc
...

yannick@ubuntu:~/uclinux-dist$
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of your path when you run `make` is not *necessarily* what it is when your command executes. I would place an `echo $PATH` in the actual `makefile` just before you attempt to compile the source file.

That will at least give an indication as to whether something is changing your path during the build process.

Comment: Excellent suggestion :)  Alternatively, just hard-code path (with something like "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" near the top of the shell script.

Comment: I've run through other problems but at least now the compiler is found as it should. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you should also add this in environmental variables

## Path to cross-tools

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-uclinux-elf-